# Como se instalar plugin de TestNg en Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Necesito instalar este plugin para poder trabajar configurar el trabajo con pruebas unitarias

Comment: Consulta el manual respectivo. Búscalo en Google. Si tienes algún problema al instalarlo, pregunta todas las veces que necesites, pero siempre recuerda seguir esta guía _[ask]_. Y de ser posible, incluye un __[mcve]__.